# Restore whatsapp messages from one number to another

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

1. Current whatsapp is linked to a non-existent number.
2. I want to create a new whatsapp account for my new existing number
3. I **do not** want to migrate my old whatsapp account to the new number.
4. If I were to move the crypto backup files of the current whatsapp, will I be able to restore it on the new account?

**Note** - 
Non existent whatsapp number is currently installed on a Moto G2, un-rooted, stock.
New number is on a Nexus 5X, rooted.

---

[Whatsapp FAQ page states the following:](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20887921)

> **Restoring or transferring a backup**
>
> WhatsApp will ask you to restore your chats and media from a backup
>   when you verify your number. Simply tap "Restore" when prompted to do
>   so. If WhatsApp does not detect a backup, it could be that:
>
> 1. You are not logged into the same Google account.  **2. You are not using the same phone number that was used to create the
>      backup.**
> 2. Your SD card and/or chat history is corrupted.
> 3. A backup file does not exist on the Google Drive account or locally
>      on the phone.

The FAQ tends to imply that it might not be possible. I'm not sure if a google drive might do the needful. Has anyone had a swing with this?

Also, rooting the G2 might not be helpful as I'll need to unlock the bootloader first - which will wipe out the internal memory anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As WhatsApp by default does not allow to transfer from a phone number to another, there's no way without root. Root would allow you to copy the encryption key and the conversation files located at `/data/data/com.whatsapp` folder to the target device.

Comment: Yes but the only problem is if i have to root the G2, then I'll first need to unlock the bootloader. And if I do that, it will trigger an instant wipe

Comment: I know, but there is no way you can do that otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can change your number in your first device i.e. Moto G2 by follwing this [link](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/wp/28060001).

After successfully doing it make a backup locally and also on google drive then install whatsapp on new device and log in with new number. You should be able to restore chat from google drive.